# Accidentally moved my Macintosh HD into 'System Volumes', unsure how to undo this

Tags: macos, mac, macos-catalina

On macOS Catalina, I ran into problems of which many I have run into with installing MongoDB. I followed [this](https://medium.com/@semmons245/arghhhh-thanks-to-the-catalina-os-update-this-now-needs-changing-987f416ebcbe) guide, but running

```
sudo mkdir -p data/db
```

inside my `/System/Volumes/Data` folder created a
seemingly duplicate Macintosh HD in the `Data` folder, and now I am unsure how to undo this action. A screenshot is shown below. How do I fix this?

[image: accidentally duplicated Macintosh HD]

Comment: I don't have Catalina to compare to, but it's quite normal to have all your mounted volumes show in there - that's where they mount to, unix-style.